# Función JS no se llama al enviar formulario

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un formulario que cuando se envia llama a una función, pero no llama a la función `valida_envia()`.

Tengo los script en archivos diferentes llamo a la función `valida_envia()` que esta ubicada en un archivo `.js`

Éste es mi código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yasp8uyv/))

```js
function valida_envia() {

  //Definimos los caracteres permitidos en una dirección de correo electrónico
  var regexp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z._.-]+\@[0-9a-zA-Z._.-]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

  //Validamos un campo o área de texto, por ejemplo el campo nombre
  if (document.form.nombre.value.length == 0) {
    alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre");
    document.form.nombre.focus();
    return 0;
  }

  if ((regexp.test(document.form.email.value) == 0) || (document.form.email.value.length = 0)) {
    alert("Introduzca una dirección de email válida");
    document.form.email.focus();
    return 0;
  } else {
    var c_email = true;
  }

  document.form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="Formulario" action="pepito123@yopmail.com" method="post" onsubmit="return valida_envia()">
  name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
  <br> email:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si revisas el ejemplo en `jsfiddle` veras que debes cambiarle donde ubicas la funcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en tu ejemplo lo has definido dentro del `onLoad` y eso es incorrecto, unicalo en el `<head>`

Edite el jsfiddle y guarde las actualizaciones, ademas pongo aqui el ejemplo aplicando las validaciones

```js
function valida_envia() {

  //Definimos los caracteres permitidos en una dirección de correo electrónico
  var regexp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z._.-]+\@[0-9a-zA-Z._.-]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

   var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
   var email = document.getElementById('email');
   
  //Validamos un campo o área de texto, por ejemplo el campo nombre
  if (nombre.value.length == 0) {
    alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre");
    nombre.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if ((regexp.test(email.value) == 0) || (email.value.length = 0)) {
    alert("Introduzca una dirección de email válida");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    var c_email = true;
  }

  document.Formulario.submit();
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="Formulario" action="pepito123@yopmail.com" method="post">
  name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
  <br> email:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="return valida_envia();">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

En el caso del JSFiddle, no se llama a la función porque tienes puesto que el código JS se ejecute "onLoad". Esto hace que la función vaya dentro de otra función (`$(document).ready(function() {})`) y su ámbito se limite a dentro de dicha función. **Si cambias el modo a "No wrap - in <head>" entonces si se llamará a la función `valida_envia`**.

Ahora, dentro de esa función hay una serie de errores:

- `document.form.nombre` y `document.form.email` no son válidos y dan error, **deberías usar una notación diferente como `document.getElementById("nombre")`** o `document.form["nombre"]`
- No devuelves 0 ó 1. Cuando devuelves un número, el segundo `return` (el que hay inline en el formulario) interpreta el 0 como "0", que no es una cadena vacía y por lo tanto es verdad y se enviará el formulario. **En su lugar devuelve *true* o *false***.

Con esos cambios el código quedaría así (también lo puedes ver en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yasp8uyv/2/)):

```
function valida_envia(e) {

  //Definimos los caracteres permitidos en una dirección de correo electrónico
  var regexp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z._.-]+\@[0-9a-zA-Z._.-]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

  //Validamos un campo o área de texto, por ejemplo el campo nombre
  if (document.getElementById("nombre").value.length == 0) {
    alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre");
    document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
    return false;
  }

  if ((regexp.test(document.getElementById("email").value) == 0) || (document.getElementById("email").value.length = 0)) {
    alert("Introduzca una dirección de email válida");
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    var c_email = true;
  }

  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos problemas principales:

- document no tiene una propiedad form, lo que tienes es una colección forms por lo que en vez de acceder a los elementos del formulario con document.form.nombre podrías hacerlo con document.forms[0].nombre (siempre y cuando sea el único form del documento)
- por otro lado si no supera la validación deberías devolver false en lugar de 0 y, si se supera, deberías devolver true en lugar de hacer el submit del formulario (el efecto es el mismo pero queda más limpio).